# How to Communicate with Web App and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, websocket

I'm attempting to make a Web app that needs to communicate to a program written in C Sharp. But I can't find a good form of communication. What I need is if a user clicks something on the Web app, it will notify the C Sharp program. Also, if an event happens on the C Sharp program, it needs to alert the Web app. Both of these are going to be running on the same machine.

Right now I'm mainly focusing on the C Sharp program just periodically "asking" what the status of the Web app is.

I've tried using POST requests to the Web app and I've had a bit of success with this but I don't know how to essentially store and update a "status" on the Web App. For example, C Sharp program sends a POST/GET request asking for the status, the Web app responds with "nothing has changed" or some sort of status code. I don't know how to keep track of that status.

I've attempted using Web Sockets but I don't think it is going to be possible on the C Sharp side. However, I'm definitely open to suggestions on how this might work.

I've tried using Socket.io with Node.js but I haven't been successful at all. I have never used Node.js before so I did a few examples and I get the very basic elements of it but I cannot set up a complete web socket. Also, I could not get Socket.io to work for me at all.

I've looked into using the ReST architectural style but I'm having a hard time understanding how I would implement it. I'm using mainly AJAX on an Apache server and most of the ReST examples I saw used IIS.

One way I've been successful with this is a horrible workaround. I use 3 files to store contents, status of Web app, and status of C Sharp program. But this requires me constantly fetching files, reading them, writing a new one, and uploading it.

This is as far as I got with a websocket that uses "ws://echo.websocket.org" to simply echo the response. I don't know how to direct the messages to a C Sharp application:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function WebSocketTest(){

            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");
            var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;

            ws.onopen = function(){
                ws.send(msg);
                alert("Message Sent: " + msg);
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (event){ 

                var received_msg = event.data;
                var response

                if(received_msg == "1"){
                    response = "Some Response";
                    alert("Message Received: " + received_msg + "\nResponse: " + response);
                }else if(received_msg == "2"){ 
                    response = "Some Response";
                    alert("Message Received: " + received_msg + "\nResponse: " + response);
                }else if(received_msg == "3"){ 
                    response = "Some Acknowledged Response";
                    alert("Message Received: " + received_msg + "\nResponse: " + response);
                }else{
                    alert("Message Received: " + received_msg);
                    response = "Command Not Recognized";
                }
                //ws.send(event.data);
            };

            ws.onclose = function(){ 
                alert("Connection is closed..."); 
            };
        }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Message to Send"></input>
        <div id="sse">
            <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
        </div>
        Type in a message to send to an "echo" Web Socket.<br>
        Message will be sent, Web Socket will send back the same message. <br>
   </body>
</html>
```

The above example will echo what gets sent and if the response happens to be a 1, 2, or 3. It will also display a custom response. This may not be exactly what I want.

For Clarification:
I would like to have a C Sharp program running in the background. Some event happens that the C Sharp program captures, it will send that event to the Web App which the user will be looking at.
Also, the Web App is running and the user clicks something so the Web App needs to send some message to the C Sharp program to handle it accordingly.

The Web App that I'm speaking of is using a bunch of Javascript/Jquery/AJAX that displays a bunch of controls to the user. The C Sharp program implements these controls to do what they are supposed to do. Let me know if I need to clarify more. A lot of this is obviously very new to me so I apologize.

NOTE: I asked this question a few days ago but I am now elaborating more and including source code. I thought about just editing the previous post but it didn't have a whole lot of insight or attention so I figured it would be better to create a new post. If I should have just edited the previous post just let me know and I will do that from now on. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if the event is raised but fails to be captured by one of the apps? Are both the node and c# apps acted on independently? Can you proxy events to the c# app through the node app so that the node app is always aware of all events? I think this really sounds like a job for message queues, but without more info it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: I definately think more clarification is in order.  Can your c# app not be a wcf service for example?

Comment: I'm very new to the C Sharp side of it so I'm not exactly sure what a WCF Service is. I'm not able to use IIS if that makes a difference. The Web App is just a "mask" of the C Sharp program. 

If an event is raised and not captured, it is fine. The user would just have to resend the command. A slight problem but liveable with for now.

Comment: I noticed this is the second time you ask this same question... Perhaps you can be more specific about the relationship between the C# app and the Web-App. Specifically (if the C# app is a 'mask'), why they aren't one unified app and what services can the C# app provide as an API access point (will it listen to regular TCP/IP sockets? is it connected to a shared database or Pub/Sub service such as Redis...?). Does the C# app have to be in C#? - Seems like you might be trying to do something simple in a complicated way...